# Port Angular JS client side application to Android

Tags: android, angularjs, google-chrome

**Context:**
On our project Bahmni (Open Source EMR for low resource non-profit health care facilities) we have an Angular JS front end. Bahmni till now has only been installed for use over intra-net. Now it will be installed in an entire country (on cloud) where it will be used by Community Health Workers from Android 4.3 phones all over the country. Since its a 3rd world country internet connectivity at best is a 2G connection and that also is a luxury, and won't be available at most places.

**Requirement:**
We want to maintain the same user experience even when the application is deployed on the cloud. And since Internet is a problem we thought enabling the application in offline mode will solve that problem. We really want to stick to the Angular JS front-end since there is a lot of active development going on that for our other implementations and the requirements are same for all users, so we really don't want to duplicate development effort of an Angular JS front-end and an Android application. The current Angular-JS codebase is huge enough to justify not migrating to something more suitable for our use-case. Google-Chrome is the only browser which works perfectly with the application.

**Current train of thought:**
What we are looking for is a way we can build a wrapper Android Application over our Angular JS front end so that it can be used in an offline mode, without Chrome's data storage limit (we are looking at storing/caching a lot of data). We are looking at Indexed-DB and Service workers and a custom sync mechanism with the main cloud when the mobile device has an internet connection to sync the captured data back to the backend.

I really don't know where to start looking for something like this. We don't have any Android expertise in the team, but have a lot of architecture expertise. What I had in mind right now was building a wrapper kind of Android Application which will enable me to a lot of data storage access without limitation on an Android device, and the build process of the APK integrates the Angular JS front-end and includes it in the APK. The other approach I was thinking about was even the Angular-JS files are pulled from the internet once when in network, and then are used from the Android application itself, which will simplify the build process and new build deployment process, but is not that elegant an approach because good Internet connectivity really is an issue. Perhaps I am thinking of this in a completely wrong way and I can just achieve it using Android's Chrome itself. But from what I have read about the Chrome storages, it is limited for web-apps unless you make it a packaged app. Which I don't think works on an Android phone.

Can someone suggest a new solution or validate the solution given above. 
I am sorry if I am not being clear, feel free to shoot any questions which I might have missed in giving context.

**Angular-JS application repository** - https://github.com/Bhamni/openmrs-module-bahmniapps

Answer (score 0):

Check out Ionic framework, it is built on top of Apache Cordova optimized for AngularJS. You will have to refactor templates to use ionics directives instead, but Ionic definately offers fast track to hybrid apps.
http://ionicframework.com/